# How to change the margins and insert the university banner in a poster?

Tags: margins, framed, beamerposter, posters

I'm trying to build up a poster. This is the template I have to use:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Jacobs Landscape Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (29/03/13)
%
% Created by:
% Computational Physics and Biophysics Group, Jacobs University
% https://teamwork.jacobs-university.de:8443/confluence/display/CoPandBiG/LaTeX+Poster
% 
% Further modified by:
% Nathaniel Johnston (nathaniel@njohnston.ca)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=0.78, size=a1]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{23.4in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{caption}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Title} % Poster title

\author{Blah Blah} % Author(s)

\institute{Department, University} % Institution(s)


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OBJECTIVES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{Objectives}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Research question}: 
\vspace{2cm}
\item \textbf{Contribution}: 
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTRODUCTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Literature review}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}

\end{block}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Model}

\end{block}


\end{column} % End of the first column

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{column}{\twocolwid} % Begin a column which is two columns wide (column 2)

\begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid] % Split up the two columns wide column

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The first column within column 2 (column 2.1)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Existence solution}


\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of column 2.1

\begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The second column within column 2 (column 2.2)

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Blah Blah}

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{Blah blah 2}

\end{block}

\end{column} % End of column 2.2

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{columns} % End of the split of column 2 - any content after this will now take up 2 columns width

\end{column} % End of the second column

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The third column

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONCLUSION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{alertblock}{Conclusion}


\end{alertblock}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{References}

\end{block}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{block}{Acknowledgements}

\small{\rmfamily{I am very grateful to ...}} \\

\end{block}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=black,bg=norange} % Change the alert block title colors
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Change the alert block body colors

\begin{alertblock}{Contact information}



\end{alertblock}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{column} % End of the third column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

To run the code, you need to download the zip folder here
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster
where you can find beamerthemeconfposter.sty and beamerposter.sty

I need your help in solving the following two issues:

1. I would like to make equal the left and right margins (still maintaining the A1 size);
2. I would need to substitute the Title section with the Title section used in this other poster template (the UCL banner can be found at http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucbpeal/Black_Landscape.pdf):

   ```
   \documentclass[a1,final]{a0poster}
   %%%Load packages
   \usepackage{multicol}           %3-column layout
   \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=0cm,top=0cm]{geometry}            %Reset margins
   \usepackage{helvet}             %Load Helvetica font & CM math
   \usepackage{color}              %Needed for colour boxes & coloured text
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   %%%Define colours and lengths
   \definecolor{headingcol}{rgb}{0.5,0.7,1}            %Colour of main title
   \definecolor{boxcol}{rgb}{0.7,0.2,0.2}      %Edge-colour of box and top banner
   \fboxsep=1cm                            %Padding between box and text
   \setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}             %Set spacing between columns
   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   %Set main text to sans-serif

   %%%Format title
   \makeatletter                           %Needed to include code in main file
   \renewcommand\@maketitle{%
   \null                                   %Sets position marker
   {
   \color{headingcol}\sffamily\Huge        %Set title font and colour
   \@title \par}%
   \vskip 0.6em%
   {
   \color{white}\sffamily\Large                %Set author font and colour
   \lineskip .5em%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
   \@author
   \end{tabular}\par}%
   \vskip 1cm
   \par
   }
   \makeatother

   \title{Making A1 scientific posters easily with \LaTeX}

   \author{Author A \& Author B\\
   University College London}

   \begin{document}
   \hspace{-3cm}                               %Align with edge of page, not margin
   \vspace{2cm}
   \includegraphics[width=844mm]{Black_Landscape.pdf}
   %\colorbox{boxcol}{                         %Coloured banner across top
   \begin{minipage}{842mm}                 %Minipage for title contents
   \vspace{-20cm}
   \maketitle
   \end{minipage}
   %}
   \vspace{-3cm}

   \begin{multicols}{3}                            %Use 3-column layout
   \raggedcolumns                          %Don't stretch contents vertically

   %%%Column1
   \section*{Introduction}

   \section*{Method}

   \columnbreak

   %%%Column 2
   \section*{Maths}

   \section*{Lists and tables}
   Itemize:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
   \item Item 3
   \end{itemize}
   \null
   Five-day forecast:
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
   Day & Summary & Max day & Min night & Wind (mph) & Visibility\\
   \hline
   Saturday & Sun/cloud & 16 & 10 & 6 & poor\\
   Sunday & Rain & 14 & 7 & 3 & poor\\
   Monday & Showers & 13 & 6 & 21 & poor\\
   Tuesday & Sun & 15 & 9 & 7 & good\\
   Wednesday & Showers & 17 & 12 & 6 &moderate
   \end{tabular}
   \end{center}


   \columnbreak

   %%%Column 3
   \section*{Discussion}

   \nocite*

   %\bibliographystyle{plain}
   %\bibliography{halobib}

   \end{multicols}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: thanks for your comment and apologies for my mistake: I have edited the question with the link to beamerthemconfposter.sty and beamerposter.sty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first half of your question:

I think your left and right margin were in fact already of the same size, the problem is, that the sum of all your columns and spaces was bigger than the available space, so that the left side was intruding the margin.

You can try and add `\begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]` and modify the size of your columns via editing `\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.20\paperwidth}` etc.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=0.78, size=a1]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{23.4in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.02\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.20\paperwidth} % Width of one column

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\title{Title} % Poster title
\author{Blah Blah} % Author(s)
\institute{Department, University} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[t]

        \begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column}    

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column}        

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column} 

        \end{columns}

    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Second part of your question:

This is only a quick and dirty solution, but if you adjust a bit the fontsizes and spaceings, you should be able to get the desired look

First you have to comment out the headline in `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`, e.g. the lines 192 to 211.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=0.78, size=a1]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{confposter} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{23.4in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.02\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.20\paperwidth} % Width of one column

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{headingcol}{rgb}{0.5,0.7,1}            %Colour of main title
\definecolor{boxcol}{rgb}{0.7,0.2,0.2}      %Edge-colour of box and top banner
\fboxsep=1cm     

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images
\usepackage{textpos}

\title{Title} % Poster title
\author{Blah Blah} % Author(s)
\institute{Department, University} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[t]    

        \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)
            \put(-13,-50){
                \begin{minipage}[t][0mm][c]{0mm}
                    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Black_Landscape.pdf} 
                \end{minipage}
            }
            \put(13,-50){
                \begin{minipage}[t][0mm][l]{500mm}
                    \textcolor{headingcol}{\sffamily \fontsize{92}{48} \selectfont \textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[1.5cm]
                    \textcolor{white}{\sffamily \fontsize{48}{48} \selectfont \textbf{\insertauthor}}\\[0.5cm]
                    \textcolor{white}{\sffamily \fontsize{48}{48} \selectfont       \textbf{\insertinstitute}}  
                \end{minipage}  
            }
        \end{picture}

        \vspace{13cm}

        \begin{columns}[t, totalwidth=\textwidth]

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column}    

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column}        

            \begin{column}{\onecolwid}
                \begin{alertblock}{test}
                \end{alertblock}
            \end{column} 

            \begin{column}{\sepwid}
            \end{column} 

        \end{columns}

    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! Any ideas for the second issue?